# how to read yii session in codeginiter controller. I am new to both the frameworks

Tags: codeigniter, session, yii

Following is the code I have used :-

```
     require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../email/apps/common/framework/YiiBase.php'));
    $config = require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../email/apps/customer/config/main.php'));
     Yii::createWebApplication($config);

 var_dump(Yii::app()->User->id);
```

i am getting following error:- 
     Message: include(): Failed opening 'Yii.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

Filename: framework/YiiBase.php

Line Number: 428

Answer (score 0):

Be kind write full absolute path for the script that executes the code and location of the files YiiBase.php and main.php.

Comment: I have used the absolute path even though i am facing the same issue

Comment: Try to include 'Yii.php' before 'YiiBase.php' or (much better way) use Yii as one piece without including saparated files.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from the [creator of Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5065-getting-everything-yii-application-offers-without-creating-one/page__view__findpost__p__26420)  says:

```
require_once('path/to/yii.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
// you can access Yii::app() now as usual
$session = Yii::app()->session;
//....use session as you wish
```

My file that can help you start is:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

**NOTE**
Its is not recommended you use YiiBase. Use either yii or yiilite. YiiBase serves as base class and is not intended to be used directly (to the best of my kowledge). Also check paths if they real point to the file!

Comment: I am getting following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include(): Failed opening 'AppInitHelper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

Filename: framework/YiiBase.php

Line Number: 428

Comment: Did you include Yii or YiiBase? Whats the hierrachy of your project file using Yii in relation to Yii?